# javaqscript: 2d associative arrays 101

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

This is my first Q&A ever, so hopefully it's alright.

As someone who generally picks stuff up quickly, I found the information on this topic was sporadic and generally over complicated, with many people saying it simply couldn't be done. so here's it broken down very simply.

Take this scenario as an example, we have a number of form components (text boxes, buttons, etc.), all with a number of properties, all of which have values... and we want to store these in a javascript array.

Comment: why downvote? is it now discouraged to share information on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my tinkerings. This code doesn't explicitly answer a question, as no question was explicitly asked, however I hope you find it useful

For good measure, here also is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cQ8Xc/

```
var $parent_arr = new Array();
var $child_arr = new Array();

//we can add the key => value pairs like so:
//(obviously they won't be done like this, more likely a loop for example)
//this works just fine $child_arr[$key] = $value;
$child_arr['Top'] = '12';
$child_arr['Left'] = '13';
$child_arr['Right'] = '14';
$child_arr['Bottom'] = '15';

//we can add the array to another array like so:
$parent_arr['component1'] = $child_arr;

//clear the array for reuse (note that it is obviously not nessecary to reuse the array)
$child_arr = [];

//refill it
//note that the child arrays don't have to be identical lengths or values
$child_arr['Height'] = '22';
$child_arr['Width'] = '23';
$child_arr['Colour'] = 'blue';

$parent_arr['component2'] = $child_arr;

//we can access the data like this:
alert($parent_arr['component1']['Top']);
alert($parent_arr['component2']['Colour']);

//these didn't work for me, you've likely seen them in other answers if you've been researching this topic
//alert(JSON.stringify($parent_arr['component1'], null, 4));
//alert(JSON.stringify($parent_arr['component1']));
//alert($parent_arr['component1'].join("\n"));

//the array can be looped over like so:
for(var component in $parent_arr) {
   for(var propertyName in $parent_arr[component]) {
      alert(component + '.' + propertyName + '=' + $parent_arr['component1'][propertyName]);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the rationale for the dollar prefix on all your variables?

Comment: the entire point was to share information in a simple form, I could have gone to the effort and made a fake question but how many people are going to have the exact same scenario? people are going to adapt the code to their own situation, so I figured why not just share the code and leave it at that?

Comment: I am aware it isn't necessary to prefix variables in javascript, but I was taught to do so, simply to make them more easily recognisable as variables. that and being used to php it comes naturally